# Invoke-Command with Computers array, access single array element inside scriptblock

Tags: arrays, powershell, invoke-command

I am wondering how to accomplish the following and hope you can help:

I want to execute several tasks on different computers by providing a array of computernames using

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerNameArray -ScriptBlock { ...}
```

Inside the scriptblock, I want to access the current ComputerName (not the whole array).

How is this possible?

I tried enclosing the Invoke-Command within a foreach loop, something like this:

```
foreach ($Computer in $ComputerNameArray)
{
 Invoke-Command-ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { ...}
}
```

which works, this way I can access the current ComputerName with `$env:Computer` but as the foreach isn't necessary here, I want to get rid of it.

Any ideas?

Thanks all!

Comment: can you post the output of `$ComputerNameArray`? have you tried creating the array like this for testing: `$ComputerNameArray = "computername1","computername2"?

Comment: Inside of the script block, you can use `$PSSenderInfo.ConnectionString -replace '^.*?//([^:]+).*','$1'` to see the array item sent to the command. This requires a successful connection to the computer. I don't see why `$env:computername` isn't sufficient in both cases.

Comment: Declaration is:  string[]]$ComputerNameArray=@( "server1", "server2")
```$env:ComputerName``` is not working, because there is no env variable called ComputerName but only ComputerNameArray. The env variable is only available if ```Invoke-Command``` is executed inside a loop. I want to get rid of the foreach loop for some elegance and code readability - sorry, regex is not an option

Comment: If you use the `-AsJob` parameter, you can see the array item in the location property that was used for that particular job. `(Get-Job).ChildJobs.Location`.

Comment: If the goal is to use the current item of the array outside of the `-Scriptblock` parameter and in another command, just use the loop. If the goal is to use the current array item inside of `-Scriptblock`, then `$env:computername` is an environment variable for that session on a Windows system and it is not necessarily the exact string you passed in.

Comment: alright, I missed that part, thank you, it is working now as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Invoke-Command $ComputerNameArray { $env:computername }
```